# Can't add element to List in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dart-null-safety

how can I add the element `first` to my List `deckList`?

`deckList.add(first);` is under lighted red  with the note:
"The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class."

```
import 'dart:ui';

class _GamingCard{
  int ?value1;
  int ?value2;
  String ?name;
  String ?type;
  Image ?image;

  _GamingCard(this.value1,this.value2,this.name,this.type,this.name);
}

class _DeckofCards{
  List<_GamingCard> ?deckList = List<_GamingCard>.empty(growable: true);

  _GamingCard first = _GamingCard(1,10,'ace','heart',null);
  _GamingCard second = _GamingCard(1,10,'ace','cross',null);
  deckList.add(first);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warring is coming from null-safety. If you like to insert data firstly, you can use constructor or provide inside list.

It can be like

```dart
 _DeckofCards() {
    deckList.add(first);
  }
```

Or just add while declaring list

```dart
class _DeckofCards {
  _GamingCard first = _GamingCard(1, 10, 'ace', 'heart', null);
  _GamingCard second = _GamingCard(1, 10, 'ace', 'cross', null);

  late List<_GamingCard> deckList = [first];
}
```

More about [`List` on dart](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/List-class.html)

One more thing, on your `_GamingCard` constructor, you didn't include `image` params, also It would be better to use named constructor for this.

More about [using-constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)